# pthread_mutex_unlock won't unlock waiting thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm writing a SIGINT handler which spawns thread that should terminate entire multithreaded process. Here's the code of terminator thread:

```
void *terminate_thread(void *data)
{
    printf("TERMINATION START\n");
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(global_mutex) != 0) {
        printf("MUTEXLOCKERROR\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("TERMINATOR LOCKED MAIN PROCESS\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < glob_n; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(thread_mutexes[i]);
        pthread_cancel(threads[i]);
        printf("THREAD %d CANCELLED\n", i);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

And here's a fragment of root thread that locks and unlocks `global_mutex`:

```
while(1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(global_mutex);
    printf("MAIN PROCESS MUTED\n");
    sleep(5);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(global_mutex);
}
```

In theory, if terminator thread unlocks `global_mutex`, and `terminate_thread` is waiting on locked mutex, it should immediately aquire that mutex. Unfortunately, this doesn't work - after unlocking mutex, root thread steals it again, which prevents terminator thread from blocking the root thread...

Is there any way to force acquiring the mutex by terminator thread instead of the root thread?

Comment: Add a `pthread_yield();` to your main loop?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your code is supposed to do, but  **1.** You cannot spawn a thread in a signal handler. Signal handlers are special Only the functions mentioned in [chapter 2.4.3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) can be called in a signal handler **2.** Only the same thread that locked a mutex can unlock it. You cannot unlock a mutex that another thread has locked.

Comment: I have a situation where, if I get a SIGINT, I need to exit all threads and then root thread before exiting app. Problem is, that all these threads can be in places that are "not safe" (these are protected by mutexes). So I'm trying to solve the problem by spawning a terminator thread, which for each thread, grabs its mutex as soon as it becomes available (meaning the thread has left "unsafe" zone), and kills the thread then.

Comment: Don't do that. Code each thread to check if it should terminate and, if so, terminate *itself*. You code each thread. If you find you have to "reach in from the outside" to make the thread do the right thing, that means you didn't code it to do the right thing, which was your job.

Comment: @KerrekSB it doesn't work :(

Comment: @qiubit: *outside* the lock?

Comment: @KerrekSB just after the unlock

Comment: the correct way to exit a thread is by calling: `pthread_exit( &status )`  not by calling `exit(0)`

Comment: to get the signal handler to kill the threads, declare a global flag.  (say `int killself = 0;`)  then in the signal handler activate that condition: `killself = 1;`  Then in each of the threads, be checking that `killself` flag with something like: `if( killself ) { status = FORCED_TO_KILL_SELF; pthread_exit( &status ); }`

Comment: @user3629249: Beware of race conditions when using this kind of global flag. See C11 draft standard `5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races, Section 4 Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.` and `Section 25 The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in
different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.`.

Comment: you may notice that the main does not give the threads a chance to grab the mutex between where the main thread unlocks the mutex and where it locks it again.  Suggest, after the call to `unlock` the mutex, to 'pause' for a bit to allow the threads to execute.  perhaps by inserting the line: `sleep(1);` or something similar

Comment: @EOF,  The only actions on that flag are 1) set it to 1 and 2) read it.  Therefore, if the reader gets a partially completed update, it will get the correct value on the next iteration.  And I'm reasonably sure that a write of an integer is an atomic operation

Comment: @user3629249: No, a write to an integer is **not** an atomic operation in any shape or form. A write to a `volatile sig_atomic_t` is atomic (but not ordered), and a write to an `_Atomic int` is atomic (and potentially ordered). While *most extant architectures* will make a naive translation of the C-code to assembly work correctly, an optimizing compiler has no obligation to emit working code, since **the behavior is undefined**.